# Random values of Int in dictionary instead of zeros

Tags: swift, struct, int

I have an `Avatar` struct. This struct has properties called elements that hold several parts of the face like `Eyes`, `Mouth` and so on. In the `init(withGender: AvatarGender)` method. I want all these elements to have their default to zero.

But instead of having zeros I get huge random Ints. I can't figure out why!

```
struct Avatar {
    var gender: AvatarGender
    var skin: AvatarSkinColor
    var elements: [AvatarElement: Int]

    var rawString: String {
      // a computed property
    }

    init(withGender: AvatarGender) {
        gender = withGender
        skin = .White
        elements = [AvatarElement: Int]()

        var allElementsType = [AvatarElement]()
        if gender == .Man {
            allElementsType = AvatarElement.allMaleValues
        } else if gender == .Woman {
            allElementsType = AvatarElement.allFemaleValues
        }
        for element in allElementsType {
            elements[element] = 0 // <= This doesn't work !!!
        }
    }

    init(fromRawString: String) {
        // Another init method that works properly
    }
}
```

Above `AvatarGender`, `AvatarSkinColor` and `AvatarElement` are enums.

Comment: The code seems right. How did you test it? Can you provide a screenshot showing the _"huge random Ints"_?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working.

Comment: Are you, by chance, viewing this in the debugger?